# Getting error Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: when trying to SSH to my server

Tags: server, ssh, display, gui, vnc

Bit of ubuntu noob but I'm trying to run a code off github on a server remotely using SSH, and the code stops at this Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

How to solve this error? I don't think I can use VNC server as I don't have root permissions. Any other way to access/enable GUI interface of server running Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should enable X11Forwarding in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and then see what happens.

Excerpt from a config file:

```
 X11Forwarding yes
 X11DisplayOffset 10
 PrintMotd no
 PrintLastLog yes
 TCPKeepAlive yes
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three ways.

1. Enable X11 through SSH

   As gmt42 said in his answer, you could enable SSH to tunnel X11 messages then the window(s) will open on your computer from which you initiated the SSH.

   In most cases, you do that using the `-X` command line option. Now if you do `man ssh` and search about X11, you'll see all sorts of options and even some examples about the capability of ssh and X11.
2. Run the tool on the server

   If you know what you're doing, you can start the application on the server. This means the window is not going to be visible to you. It will be visible on the server. In most cases, this only works if you are logged in an X11 session. (i.e. if someone else is logged in or no one is logged in, it probably won't work)

   This is done by setting `DISPLAY` before running the command:

   ```
    DISPLAY=:0 cmd
   ```

   This means open the display screen 0 on `localhost`.
3. Setup and Start the Remote Desktop

   In the Ubuntu preferences, you have a ["Screen Sharing"](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-remote-desktop-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) or something like that. (I have Ubuntu 18.04, that's what it's called for now). That opens creates a form of VPN and you can connect to that. It uses port 5900 and you'll want to setup a login and password to allow the access. If you have Ubuntu on both sides, it should be really easy. I used Remmina and it worked as expected.

   You'll have to open access to the port if you have a firewall. This can also be done with an SSH tunnel (which is probably not any slower but adds a layer of protection).

[image]